# How to get all rows of a specific table of a database in android correctly

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am trying to use SQLlite database and I made two tables inside it, one of them called users which contain each user credentials. I made a method called "`getAllUsersRows()`" to get all rows in the table, the intent does not start when I entered the initial  user "TRUST" :

```
package com.example.welcome.madrasti;

    import android.animation.Animator;
    import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
    import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
     */
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        private EditText uPassword;
        private EditText uName;
        Intent intent;
        DBAdapter db;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            openDB();

            uPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

            uName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

            Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up);

            Button signInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in);

            intent = getIntent();

            signInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    attemptLogin();
                }
            });

            register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    attemptRegister();
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            closeDB();

        }// end onDestroy method



        //**///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**//

        private void openDB() {
            db = new DBAdapter(this);
            db.open();
        } // end openDB method

        //**///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**//

        private void closeDB() {
            db.close();
        } // end closeDB method


        //**///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**//


        //**///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**//

        private void attemptRegister() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddUser.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        //**///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**//

        /**
         * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
         * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
         * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
         */
        private void attemptLogin() {


            db.open();

            Cursor cursor = db.getAllUsersRows();

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {


                if (cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_NAME_TABLE_1).equals(uName.getText().toString()) && cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_PASSWD_TABLE_1).equals(uPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    if (cursor.getInt(DBAdapter.COL_ADMIN_TABLE_1) == 1) {


                        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {


                        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "إسم المستخدم أو كلمة السر خاطئة" + "\n" + "حاول مرة أخرى أو أنشئ حساب!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            }


            cursor.close();


        }

    }
```

The following is the whole database class:

```
package com.example.welcome.madrasti;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter  {

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    //columns names users
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWD = "passwd";
    public static final String KEY_ADMIN = "isAdmin";
    public static final String KEY_U_PHONE = "phone";

    // School Table Columns names
    public static final String KEY_SCHOOLID = "schoolID";
    public static final String KEY_SCHOOLNAME = "schoolName";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE_NUM = "schoolPhone";
    public static final String KEY_MATERIALS = "schoolExtraM";
    public static final String KEY_FOUNDATION_DATE = "schoolFD";
    public static final String KEY_CLASSES = "schoolClasses";
    public static final String KEY_BUY_BOOKS = "schoolGetBooks";
    public static final String KEY_HEALTH = "schoolHealthSituation";
    public static final String KEY_LABORATORIES = "schoolLabs";
    public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "schoolLocation";
    public static final String KEY_FEES = "schoolFees";
    public static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "schoolLatitude";
    public static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "schoolLongitude";
    public static final String KEY_SChOOL_TYPE = "schoolType";


    //columns numbers - users
    public static final int COL_ROWID_TABLE_1 = 0;
    public static final int COL_NAME_TABLE_1 = 1;
    public static final int COL_PASSWD_TABLE_1 = 2;
    public static final int COL_ADMIN_TABLE_1 = 3;
    public static final int COL_PHONE_NUM_TABLE_1 = 4;

    //columns numbers - schools
    public static final int COL_SCHOOLID_TABLE_2 = 0;
    public static final int COL_SCHOOLNAME_TABLE_2 = 1;
    public static final int COL_PHONE_NUM_TABLE_2 = 2;
    public static final int COL_MATERIALS_TABLE_2 = 3;
    public static final int COL_FOUNDATION_DATE_TABLE_2 = 4;
    public static final int COL_CLASSES_TABLE_2 = 5;
    public static final int COL_BUY_BOOKS_TABLE_2 = 6;
    public static final int COL_HEALTH_TABLE_2 = 7;
    public static final int COL_LABORATORIES_TABLE_2 = 8;
    public static final int COL_LOCATION_TABLE_2 = 9;
    public static final int COL_FEES_TABLE_2 = 10;
    public static final int COL_LATITUDE_TABLE_2 = 11;
    public static final int COL_LONGITUDE_TABLE_2 = 12;
    public static final int COL_SChOOL_TYPE_TABLE_2 = 13;



    // array for the columns names
    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS_TABLE_1 = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PASSWD, KEY_ADMIN,KEY_U_PHONE};

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS_TABLE_2 = new String[] {KEY_SCHOOLID, KEY_SCHOOLNAME, KEY_PHONE_NUM, KEY_MATERIALS,KEY_FOUNDATION_DATE,KEY_CLASSES,KEY_BUY_BOOKS,KEY_HEALTH,KEY_LABORATORIES,KEY_LOCATION,KEY_FEES,KEY_LATITUDE,KEY_LONGITUDE,KEY_SChOOL_TYPE};

    // the database name and the table name
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_1 = "users";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_2 = "schools";
    // version 
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;   

    // create table query
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL_1 =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_1
                    + "("
                    + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    + KEY_NAME+ " text not null,"
                    + KEY_PASSWD + " text not null,"
                    +KEY_ADMIN  + " integer not null,"
                    + KEY_U_PHONE  + " text not null"  + ")";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL_2 =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_2
                    + "("
                    + KEY_SCHOOLID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    + KEY_SCHOOLNAME + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_PHONE_NUM + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_MATERIALS + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_FOUNDATION_DATE + " integer not null,"
                    + KEY_CLASSES + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_BUY_BOOKS + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_HEALTH + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_LABORATORIES + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_FEES + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_LOCATION + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_LONGITUDE + " double not null,"
                    + KEY_SChOOL_TYPE + " text not null,"
                    + KEY_LATITUDE + " double not null"  + ")";



    private final Context context;

    // initiates instances from class DatabaseHelper and SQLiteDatabase 
    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db; // database


    // constructor
    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {


        this.context = ctx;
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    }


    public DBAdapter open() {
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }


    public void close() {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }


    public long insertSchool(String name, String phone,String materials, int fDate,String classes,String books,String health,String labs,String fees,String location,double longitude,String type,double latitude) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE_NUM,phone);
        initialValues.put(KEY_MATERIALS, materials);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FOUNDATION_DATE, fDate);
        initialValues.put(KEY_CLASSES, classes);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BUY_BOOKS, books);
        initialValues.put(KEY_HEALTH,health);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LABORATORIES, labs);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FEES, fees);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        initialValues.put(KEY_SChOOL_TYPE, type);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LATITUDE, latitude);


        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_2, null, initialValues);
    }

    public long insertUser(String name, String passwd,int isAdmin, String phone) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWD, passwd);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ADMIN, isAdmin);
        initialValues.put(KEY_U_PHONE, phone);


        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_1, null, initialValues);
    }


    public boolean deleteShool(String schoolName) {
        String where = KEY_SCHOOLNAME + "='" + schoolName + "'";
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_2, where, null) != 0;
    }


        public boolean deleteSchoolById(long rowId) {
            String where = KEY_SCHOOLID + "=" + rowId;
            return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_2, where, null) != 0;
        }

    public void deleteAll() {
        Cursor c = getAllRows();
        long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_SCHOOLID);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                deleteSchoolById(c.getLong((int) rowId));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }


    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_2, ALL_KEYS_TABLE_2,
                            where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }


    public Cursor getAllUsersRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_1, ALL_KEYS_TABLE_1,
                where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }


    public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_SCHOOLID+ "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_2, ALL_KEYS_TABLE_2,
                        where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }



    public Cursor getRowByName(String name) {
        String where = KEY_SCHOOLNAME + "='" + name+"'";
        Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_2, ALL_KEYS_TABLE_2,
                        where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }



    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {

            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL_1);
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL_2);

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, "TRUST");
            initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWD, "792863");
            initialValues.put(KEY_ADMIN, 1);
            initialValues.put(KEY_U_PHONE, "0799504863");

            _db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_1, null, initialValues);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                    + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");


             _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_1);
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_2);


            onCreate(_db);



        }
    }



}
```

Kindy tell me where is the problem and how to fix it.

LogCat:

```
04-08 11:49:15.583 3163-3163/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10059: Read-only file system
04-08 11:49:15.583 3163-3163/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
04-08 11:49:15.584 3163-3163/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-08 11:49:15.829 3163-3163/com.example.welcome.madrasti I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-08 11:49:15.893 3163-3163/com.example.welcome.madrasti W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-08 11:49:16.005 3163-3184/com.example.welcome.madrasti D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-08 11:49:16.729 3163-3163/com.example.welcome.madrasti D/Atlas: Validating map...
04-08 11:49:17.985 3163-3184/com.example.welcome.madrasti D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
04-08 11:49:17.986 3163-3184/com.example.welcome.madrasti D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
04-08 11:49:17.996 3163-3184/com.example.welcome.madrasti D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
04-08 11:49:18.071 3163-3184/com.example.welcome.madrasti I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-08 11:49:18.493 3163-3184/com.example.welcome.madrasti D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
04-08 11:49:18.515 3163-3184/com.example.welcome.madrasti W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-08 11:49:18.515 3163-3184/com.example.welcome.madrasti W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xeec35720, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-08 11:49:18.550 3163-3163/com.example.welcome.madrasti I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-08 11:49:21.172 3163-3163/com.example.welcome.madrasti I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
04-08 11:49:21.176 3163-3163/com.example.welcome.madrasti I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
04-08 11:49:23.259 3163-3184/com.example.welcome.madrasti W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-08 11:49:23.259 3163-3184/com.example.welcome.madrasti W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe2c122c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-08 11:49:23.377 3163-3163/com.example.welcome.madrasti W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
04-08 11:49:23.384 3163-3163/com.example.welcome.madrasti I/Choreographer: Skipped 129 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-08 11:49:24.297 3163-3163/com.example.welcome.madrasti I/Choreographer: Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-08 11:50:00.123 3163-3184/com.example.welcome.madrasti W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-08 11:50:00.123 3163-3184/com.example.welcome.madrasti W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe2c18ee0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: Please post the log of the error , otherwise its difficult to find out what the problem is.

Comment: Where to find it ?

Comment: post the log errors...in the bottom of AS find logcat press select all  and post it here??

Comment: @SushobhNadiger ; I updated my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue you are having is because you have omitted a space between the column name **phone** and the column type as per :-

`+ KEY_U_PHONE  + "text not null"  + ")";`

so instead of the column name being phone it will be **phonetext**.

To fix this use :-

```
// create table query
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL_1 =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE_1
                + "("
                + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + KEY_NAME+ " text not null,"
                + KEY_PASSWD + " text not null,"
                +KEY_ADMIN  + " integer not null,"
                + KEY_U_PHONE  + " text not null"  + ")"; //<<<< SPACE ADDED before text not null
```

You will then need to do one of the following :-

- Delete/Clear the App's data.
- uninstall the App.
- increase the Database version

and then rerun the App.

The error, i.e. that there is no **phone** column, would have been evident in the stack trace which would have been like :-

```
04-08 12:02:18.919 1373-1373/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) table users has no column named phone
04-08 12:02:18.919 1373-1373/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting passwd=792863 phone=0799504863 isAdmin=1 name=TRUST
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table users has no column named phone (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO users(passwd,phone,isAdmin,name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
        at soanswers.soanswers.DBAdapter$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DBAdapter.java:254)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at soanswers.soanswers.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:123)
        at soanswers.soanswers.MainActivity.SO49717212(MainActivity.java:70)
        at soanswers.soanswers.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 12:02:18.927 1373-1373/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: phone
04-08 12:02:18.927 1373-1373/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-08 12:02:18.927 1373-1373/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6261288)
04-08 12:02:18.927 1373-1373/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{soanswers.soanswers/soanswers.soanswers.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: phone (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT id, name, passwd, isAdmin, phone FROM users
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: phone (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT id, name, passwd, isAdmin, phone FROM users
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
        at soanswers.soanswers.DBAdapter.getAllUsersRows(DBAdapter.java:203)
        at soanswers.soanswers.MainActivity.SO49717212(MainActivity.java:72)
        at soanswers.soanswers.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: As you only have 1 user using `cursor.moveToFirst();` will move to that row. By then using `while(cursor.moveToNext())` the move to another row cannot be done so the while loop finishes with nothing done. Simplest way would be to remove the `cursor.moveToFirst()`.